# PHP form and validation not working

Tags: php, forms, validation, form-submit

My form worked before and now that I added the confirmation popup at the bottom, it no longer works. I don't know what is going on and I'm hoping getting a second set of eyes on this will reveal my mistake. Thank you in advance for looking at this!

```
<?php #Registration 

//Arrays
$months = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
$season = array('Fall 2014', 'Winter 2014', 'Spring 2015', 'Summer 2015');
$days = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31');
$locations = array('Priest River', 'Sandpoint', 'Online');

function makeSafe($value) { 
    return stripslashes(trim($value)); 
}

//Form Subitted
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    //form submitted through post, do validation

    $authorization = (!empty($_POST['authorization'])) ? makeSafe($_POST['authorization']) : '';
    $signature = (!empty($_POST['signature'])) ? makeSafe($_POST['signature']) : '';    
    $cc = makeSafe($_POST['cc']);
    $ll = makeSafe($_POST['ll']);
    $fname = makeSafe($_POST['fname']);
    $mname = makeSafe($_POST['mname']);
    $lname = makeSafe($_POST['lname']);
    $pname = makeSafe($_POST['pname']);
    $mm = makeSafe($_POST['mm']);
    $dd = makeSafe($_POST['dd']);
    $year = makeSafe($_POST['year']);
    $age = makeSafe($_POST['age']);
    $school = makeSafe($_POST['school']);
    $address = makeSafe($_POST['address']);
    $city = makeSafe($_POST['city']);
    $state = makeSafe($_POST['state']);
    $zip = makeSafe($_POST['zip']);
    $gender = makeSafe($_POST['gender']);
    $email = makeSafe($_POST['email']);
    $phone = makeSafe($_POST['phone']);
    $altph = makeSafe($_POST['altph']);
    $sn = makeSafe($_POST['sn']);
    $hp = makeSafe($_POST['hp']);
    $packet = (!empty($_POST['signature'])) ? makeSafe($_POST['packet']) : '';
    $message = '';
    $problem = FALSE;

    //Check Season Selected DropDown Array
    if(isset($_POST['cc']) && !empty($_POST['cc']))
    {
        // if cc is in $season array
        if(in_array($_POST['cc'], $season))
        {
            // this value is not accepted or "- Select Season -" selected
        }
        else
        {
           $seasonMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
        }
    }

    //Check Class Location Selected DropDown Array
    if(isset($_POST['ll']) && !empty($_POST['ll']))
    {
        // if ll is in $locations array
        if(in_array($_POST['ll'], $locations))
        {
            // this value is not accepted or "- Select Location -" selected
        }
        else
        {
           $locationMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
        }
    }

    //Check Birth Month Selected DropDown Array
    if(isset($_POST['mm']) && !empty($_POST['mm']))
    {
        // if mm is in $months array
        if(in_array($_POST['mm'], $months))
        {
            // this value is not accepted or "- Select Month -" selected
        }
        else
        {
           $monthMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
        }
    }

    //Check Birth Day Selected DropDown Array
    if(isset($_POST['dd']) && !empty($_POST['dd']))
    {
        // if dd is in $day array
        if(in_array($_POST['dd'], $days))
        {
            // this value is not accepted or "- Select Day -" selected
        }
        else
        {
           $dayMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
        }
    }

    //Check Gender
    //if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
        //$genderMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    //}

    //Check Read Authorization
    if($_POST['authorizaton']!="1" AND $_POST['packet']!="1"){
        $problem = TRUE;
        $parentMessage .= '<p class="errorClass parentMsg">Please read and check the boxes below.</p>';
    }

    //Check Electronic Signature
    if($_POST['signature']!="1"){
        $problem = TRUE;
        $signatureMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    }

    //Check First Name
    if (!eregi ('^[[:alpha:]\.\' \-]{2,}$',$fname)) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        $fnameMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    }

    //Check Last Name
    if (!eregi ('^[[:alpha:]\.\' \-]{2,}$',$lname)) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        $lnameMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    }

    //Check Parent/Guardian Name
    if (!eregi ('^[[:alpha:]\.\' \-\ ]{2,}$',$pname)) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        $pnameMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    }

    //Check School Name
    if (!eregi ('^[[:alnum:]\.\' \-\,]{4,}$', $school)) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        $schoolMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    }

    //Check Student Address
    if (!eregi ('^[[:alnum:]\.\' \#\-]{4,}$', $address)) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        $addyMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    }

    //Check City
    if (!eregi ('^[[:alpha:]\.\' \-]{4,}$', $city)) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        $cityMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    }

    //Check State
    if (!eregi ('^[[:alpha:]\.\' \-\ ]{2,2}$', $state)) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        $stateMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    }

    //Check Email
    if (!eregi ('^[[:alnum:]][a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$',$email)) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        $emailMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    }

    //Check Zip
    if (!eregi ('^[0-9]{5}(\-[0-9]{4})?$',$zip)) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        $zipMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    }

    //Check Phone
    if (!eregi ('^[0-9.\(\)\-\ ]{10,14}$', $phone)) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        $phoneMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    }

    //Check Age 
    if(!eregi('^[0-9]{2}$',$age)) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        $ageMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    }

    //Check Year
    if(!eregi('^[0-9]{2,4}$',$year)) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        $yearMessage .= '<p class="errorClass">Required</p>';
    }

    if ($problem == TRUE) {//Something went wrong
        echo $message;
        echo '';        
    }
    else{   
        $to = "webangel119@yahoo.com";
        $subject = "Buckle-Up New Student Registration for $fname $lname";
        $headers = 'From: webangel119@yahoo.com' . "\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        $msg .= "PLAIN TEXT EMAIL\n\n";
        $msg .= "Location: $ll      Class: $cc\n\n";
        $msg .= "Name: $fname $mname $lname\n\n";
        $msg .= "Parent/Guardian Name: $pname\n\n";
        $msg .= "Birthday: $mm $day $year     Age: $age     Gender: $gender\n\n";
        $msg .= "School: $school\n\n";
        $msg .= "Address: $address\n\n";
        $msg .= "City: $city     State: $state     Zip Code: $zip\n\n";
        $msg .= "Phone: $phone     Alternate Contact: $altph\n\n";
        $msg .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $msg .= "Special Needs: $sn\n\n";
        $msg .= "Health Problems or Allergies: $hp\n\n";
        $msg .= "I Parent/Guardian understand the traffic safety education course consists of 30 clock-hours of classroom instruction, 6 hours of behind-the-wheel instruction and 6 hours of in-car observation. I also understand that instruction is provided by a properly certified instructor licensed by the Idaho Department of Education and the Idaho Bureau of Occupational Licenses, and the behind-the-wheel training takes place in a dual-control vehicle that is adequately insured. I accept the fact that the Buckle-UP Driving School, LLC will not be responsible for any driving the student may do outside the Driver Education program. In addition I acknowledge that portions of the student participation in this traffic safety education course may be videotaped for feedback and grading as well as for use in future training courses.\n\n";
        $msg .= "I Parent/Guardian have read the student/parent or guardian information packet for Driver Education and hereby give approval for the above student to participate in the course.\n\n";
        $msg .= "Parent/Guardian Authorized Signature: Electronically Signed\n\n"; 

        if(mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers) == false){
            // Email failed
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('failed!')</script>";
        }
        else {
            echo
            $authorization = '';
            $ll = '';
            $cc = '';   
            $fname = '';
            $mname = '';
            $lname = '';
            $pname = '';
            $mm = '';
            $dd = '';
            $year = '';
            $age = '';
            $school = '';
            $address = '';
            $city = '';
            $state = '';
            $zip = '';
            $gender = '';
            $email = '';
            $phone = '';
            $altph = '';
            $hp = '';
            $sn = '';
            $signature = '';
            $packet = '';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<form id="registration" class="registrationSettings" name="registration" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="myFunction();return false")>
<div class="formHeading">DRIVER EDUCATION ENROLLMENT FORM</div>
<section>       
<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">Location</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $locationMessage; ?>
    <select name="ll" class="select-form-style">
      <option>- Select Location -</option>
        <?php 
          foreach ($locations as $location) {
          $selected = (!empty($ll) && $ll == $location) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $location;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $location;?></option>
        <?php
          }
        ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">Schedule</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $seasonMessage; ?>
    <select name="cc" class="select-form-style">
      <option>- Select Schedule -</option>
        <?php
          foreach ($season as $season) {
          $selected = (!empty($cc) && $cc == $season) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $season;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $season;?></option>
        <?php
          }
        ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">First Name</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $fnameMessage; ?>
<input type="text" title="First Name" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" 
maxlength="32" class="fnameField" autocomplete="on" />
</div>            
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p>Middle</p></div>
  <div class="field"> 
<input type="text" title="Middle Name" name="mname" value="<?php echo $mname; ?>" 
maxlength="20" class="mnameField" autocomplete="on" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">Last Name</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $lnameMessage; ?>
<input type="text" title="Last Name" name="lname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>" 
maxlength="32" class="lnameField" autocomplete="on" />
</div>
</div> 

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">Parent/Guardian Name</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $pnameMessage; ?>
<input type="text" title="Parent Name" name="pname" value="<?php echo $pname; ?>" 
maxlength="32" class="pnameField" autocomplete="on" />
</div>            
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">Birthday</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $monthMessage; ?>
<select name="mm" class="select-form-style">
<option>
- Select Month -
</option>
<?php
foreach ($months as $month) {
$selected = (!empty($mm) && $mm == $month) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
?>
<option value="<?php echo $month;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>>
<?php echo $month;?>
</option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">Day</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $dayMessage; ?>
    <select name="dd" class="select-form-style">
      <option>- Select Day -</option>
        <?php
          foreach ($days as $day) {
          $selected = (!empty($dd) && $dd == $day) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $day;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $day;?></option>
        <?php
          }
        ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">Year</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $yearMessage; ?>
<input type="text" title="Year" name="year" value="<?php echo $year; ?>" 
maxlength="4" class="byearField" autocomplete="on" /> 
</div>
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">Age</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $ageMessage; ?>
<input type="text" title="Age" name="age" value="<?php echo $age; ?>" 
maxlength="2" class="ageField" autocomplete="on" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="radioFieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">Gender</p></div>
  <div class="field"> 
  <div class="radioGroup">
<input type="radio" id="genderSelectMale" class="" name="gender" value="Male" />
<label for="genderSelectMale"><span></span>Male</label> 
<input type="radio" id="genderSelectFemale" class="" name="gender" value="Female" />
<label for="genderSelectFemale"><span></span>Female</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">School</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $schoolMessage; ?> 
<input type="text" title="School" name="school" value="<?php echo $school; ?>" 
maxlength="30" class="schoolField" autocomplete="on" />
</div>
</div> 

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">Home Address</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $addyMessage; ?> 
<input type="text" title="Street Address" name="address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>" 
maxlength="30" class="addyField" autocomplete="on" />
</div>
</div>      

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">City</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $cityMessage; ?> 
<input type="text" title="City" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" 
class="cityField" autocomplete="on" />
</div>
</div>  

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">State</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $cityMessage; ?>
<input type="text" title="State" name="state" value="<?php echo $state; ?>" 
maxlength="2" class="stateField" autocomplete="on" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">Zip</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $zipMessage; ?>
<input type="text" title="Zip Code" name="zip" value="<?php echo $zip; ?>" 
maxlength="9" class="zipField" autocomplete="on" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">Phone</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $phoneMessage; ?> 
<input type="text" title="Phone Number" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" 
maxlength="14" class="phoneField" autocomplete="on" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p>Alternate Phone</p></div>
  <div class="field">
<input type="text" title="Alternate Phone Number" name="altph" value="<?php echo $altph; ?>" 
maxlength="14" class="altPhoneField" autocomplete="on" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p class="bold">Email</p></div>
  <div class="field"><?php echo $emailMessage; ?> 
<input type="text" title="Email Address" name="email" value='<?php echo $email; ?>'
maxlength="30" class="emailField" autocomplete="on" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="fieldBox">
  <div class="label"><p>Special Needs</p></div>
  <div class="field">
  <div class="GroupSelect">
<Input type = 'Checkbox' id="sn" Name='sn' class="sn" value="Yes" <?php echo 
(!empty($sn)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';?> /><label for="sn"><span></span></label>  
</div>
</div>
</div> 

<p class="textareaStyle">
Health Problems or Allergies
<textarea name="hp" value='<?php echo $hp; ?>' class="healthAllergyField" 
id="contact"></textarea>
</p>
</section>
<section class="agreement"><?php echo $parentMessage; ?>                

<p class="bold">
PARENT/GUARDIAN AUTHORIZATION:
</p>
<section>
<Input type = 'Checkbox' id="autho" Name ='authorization' class="authorization" value ="1" <?php echo 
(!empty($authorization)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';?> /><label for="autho"><span></span>I understand the traffic 
safety education course consists of 30 clock-hours of classroom instruction, 6 
hours of behind-the-wheel instruction and 6 hours of in-car observation. I also 
understand that instruction is provided by a properly certified instructor licensed
by the Idaho Department of Education and the Idaho Bureau of Occupational Licenses,
and the behind-the-wheel training takes place in a dual-control vehicle that is 
adequately insured. I accept the fact that the Buckle-UP Driving School, LLC will 
not be responsible for any driving the student may do outside the Driver Education 
program. In addition I acknowledge that portions of the student participation in 
this traffic safety education course may be videotaped for feedback and grading as 
well as for use in future training courses. </label>
</section>
<section>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="parentPack" title="Packet" name="packet" value="1" <?php echo 
(!empty($packet)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';?> /><label for="parentPack"><span></span>I have read the <a href=
"pdf_server.php?file=pdfs/BUCKLE_UP_INFORMATION_PACKET" class="registerLink">Student/Parent or Guardian 
Information Packet</a><a href=
"pdfs/BUCKLE_UP_INFORMATION_PACKET.pdf" class="registerLinkMobile">Student/Parent or Guardian 
Information Packet</a> for Driver Education and hereby give approval for the above 
student to participate in the course.</label>
</p>    
</section>  
<div class="signature">    
<section>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="signature" title="Parent/Guardian Signature" name="signature" value="1" <?php echo 
(!empty($signature)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';?> /><label for="signature"><span></span>By checking this box you are registering the above student for Driver's Education with Buckle-Up Driving School and are stating the above information is accurate to the best of your knowlegde. Any false statements or registration by anyone other than the Parent/Guardian can and will be held accountable by the laws within your State. The registration fee of $275 for class in Priest River/Sandpoint will need to be paid in full by the end of the class and $375 for the online class.</label>
</p>    
</section>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="formButton">
</div>
</section>
</form>
```

Comment: What kind of error are you facing it? check php_error_log or add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beggining of you file.

Comment: Too much code. Point us to the place where you are having trouble and tell us what error results, what is not happening, etc. If you comment out the part you just added does the problem go away?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. nothing comes to the email address

Comment: As Peter mentioned its impossible to follow your code and no wonder you have issues with it as well the only way you could actually fix it is by debugging using xdebug

Comment: Your `makeSafe` function is completely pointless, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the much else I can see the problem with posting without an action and diverting the action to a javascript snippet which does not exist in the code posted to your question. So the form will not post because the following tells it not to but to send the click event to the missing javascript.

```
action="#" onsubmit="myFunction();return false")
```

Your post is too incomplete for answer.  But what I did was remove the offending attributes to make the form postback to the code.

What you should do is what I did. Use Wampserver locally (Mamp if on a Mac). Then make a single page with the code. Xdebug is built in to wampserver so you will get an immediate stack trace. This will help you work through the errors which are too many to list here.

Using firebug in Mozilla is also a good thing to do. With you will see that the click submit is sending to a non-existent or buggy javascript function.